# Kotlin Jackson Mapper deserializing String as HashMap<String, Any> instead of type

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, jackson

I defined a method:

```
protected inline fun <reified T : Any> executeForEntity(httpUriRequest: HttpUriRequest): T {
    return httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest) { response: HttpResponse ->
        val status = response.statusLine.statusCode
        if (status == 200) {
            val content = EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)
            // this is the Jackson default readValue()
            objectMapper.readValue(content, T::class.java)
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("Service error occurred, status=${response.statusLine.statusCode}, content=${EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)}")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to:

```
val entities: List<Entity> = getForEntity("/api/v1/my-entities")
```

However, instead of getting a list of entities, Jackson come back with an ArrayList of HashMaps? Even with explicit type declaration... This is fairly bizarre what is happening?

Using the jackson kotlin module's extension method makes the errors even worse. Are generics not supported in these use-cases?

Comment: You need to provide `Class<T> clazz` as second argument and provide it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this "T" could be a collection, and Java type erasure make that impossible

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TypeReference` like this

```
objectMapper.readValue<T>(json, object : TypeReference<T>() {})
```